# Type preservation failing with RemoteClass

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Consider the following example dataclass:

```
[RemoteClass]
public class SOTestData {
    public var i:int;
    public function SOTestData(i:int) {
        this.i = i;
    }   
}
```

As I understand, the RemoteClass metadata-tag should ensure that when an object of this class gets sreialized, the type information is preserved.

I used the following program to test:

```
public class SOTest extends Sprite {
    public function SOTest() {
        var data:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("SOTest");
        if (data.data.object) {
            try {
                var stored:SOTestData = data.data.object;
                trace(stored.i);
            } finally {
                data.clear();
            }
        }
        else {
            data.data.object = new SOTestData(15);
            data.flush();
        }
    }   
}
```

Here the first run writes the data, seconds reads and clears. Running this, I still get a class cast error. Indeed, in the SharedObject there is no type information stored.

I don't think i'm using the metadata wrong, could it maybe be that the compiler doesn't know what to do with it? I don't get any compiler errors/warnings, although when i use some inexistant tag it doesn't complain either. I'm using Flex 4.6 SDK with FlashDevelop as IDE.

**EDIT:**

Below is the shared object. As you can see, the type is saved as "Object" instead of the actual type.

```
so = [object #2, class 'SharedObject'] {
  data: [object #0, class 'Object'] {
    object: [object #1, class 'Object', dynamic 'False', externalizable 'False'] {
      i: 15,
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've only used RemoteClass for making AMF RemoteObject calls; I didn't think it had anything to do w/ Shared Objects.  Per the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/metadata_3.html#198729)

> Use the [RemoteClass] metadata tag to register the class with Flex so
>   that Flex preserves type information when a class instance is
>   serialized by using Action Message Format (AMF). You insert the
>   [RemoteClass] metadata tag before an ActionScript class definition.
>   The [RemoteClass] metadata tag has the following syntax:

As best I can tell from the code you provided, you are not serializing the object in AMF format.

I believe your class cast error is due to the fact that you aren't casting your class.  Shared Objects always come back as generic Objects.  Try this:

```
var stored:SOTestData = data.data.object as SOTestData ;
```

---

Here is some code from an application I use.  First the value object which will get serialized in a shared object:

```
package com.login.vos
{

    [RemoteClass(alias="com.login.vos.UserVO")]
    public class UserVO
    {
        public function UserVO()
        {
        } 

        public var firstName :String;
        public var lastName :String;
        public var userID :Number;
    }
}
```

The the code to save the object:

```
    public static function saveUserVO(userVO:UserVO):void{
        var userSharedObject :SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('userVO')  ;
        userSharedObject.data.userVO = userVO;
        userSharedObject.flush();
    }
```

And finally, the code to load the objecT:

```
    public static function getUserVO():UserVO{
        var userSharedObject :SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal('userVO')
        if(userSharedObject.size <=0){
            return null;
        }
        return userSharedObject.data.userVO as UserVO;

    }
```

The only obvious difference between this and the code by the original poster is that I'm specifying an alias in the RemoteClass metadata.

Comment: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_keep_the_type_of_your_objects_when_serializ-8323.html. Also, casting it like that does the exact same. The problem is that on serializing the type gets lost; it cannot be recovered by casting in any way.

Comment: I had no idea that Shared Object were stored in AMF format.  I haven't been able to find that information replicated in any way.  I checked in some old code of mine; and I am creating a new object instance and manually copying over the properties stored in the shared object.

Comment: Oh, and I just found another example where I am casting it as above.  The only difference is I specify an alias in the RemoteClass metadata.

Comment: Adding an alias doesn't seem to make any difference. Also it appears that the compiler does know how to handle the metadata tags, as adding [Deprecated] to a method does cause a warning.
However, it does seem like casting in the way you did does make a difference. Now i don't get an error anymore, but it always returns null...

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why it would work for me; but not for you.

Comment: So am I :-/ I'm working with a dirty manual (de)serialization for now, but this will get unmanageable once my class hierarchy grows.